# MvxBind Click on Button doesnt work in MvxGridView

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have problem with Android app in Xamarin. I have MenuCardView.axml where is MvxGridView with ItemSource but I dont want use here ItemClick. I want use MvxBind Click in MvxItemTemplate on Button there. But Click doesnt work here.

**Here is my MenuCardView.axml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="0">
    <TableRow>
         <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <MvxGridView
                    android:id="@+id/menuCardDetailGrid"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource MenuItems"
                    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/menucarddetailitemview"
                    android:numColumns="1"
                    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
                    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_color_selector"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="300dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp" />
         </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

**Here is my MenuCardDetailItemView.axml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/menucarddetailitemview">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
            <TextView
                local:MvxBind="Text Name"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:lines="2"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:layout_width="185dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">
            <TextView
                local:MvxBind="Text Price"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
            <Button
                local:MvxBind="Click MenuItemClickCommand"
                android:background="@color/red"
                android:text="CLICK"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/buttonMenuDetail"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="13dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**And here is my MenuCardViewModel.cs:**

```
public class MenuCardViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public MenuCardViewModel(IMvxMessenger messenger) : base(messenger)
    {
    }

    public void Init(Menu menu)
    {
        Header = menu.Header;
        InitializeMenuItems(menu);
    }

    private void InitializeMenuItems(Menu menu)
    {
        if (menu.MenuItemsList == null)
        {
            var offline = Mvx.Resolve<IOfflineContent>();
            var loadedMenu = offline.GetMenuDetailFromApi(menu.Id);
            MenuItems = loadedMenu.MenuItemsList;
        }
        else
        {
            MenuItems = menu.MenuItemsList;
        }
    }

    private string _header;
    public string Header
    {
        get { return _header; }
        set
        {
            _header = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Header);
        }
    }

    private List<MenuItem> _menuItems;
    public List<MenuItem> MenuItems
    {
        get { return _menuItems; }
        set
        {
            _menuItems = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => MenuItems);
        }
    }

    private ICommand _menuItemClickCommand;
    public ICommand MenuItemClickCommand
    {
        get
        {
            _menuItemClickCommand = _menuItemClickCommand ?? new MvxCommand(DoMenuItemClickCommand);
            return _menuItemClickCommand;
        }
    }

    private void DoMenuItemClickCommand()
    {
        // code here...
    }
}
```

I want bind MenuItemClickCommand on my Button in MenuCardVideDetailView. Some tips how solve this problem?

**UPDATE:**

I tried this it works but I dont know if this is good solution:

```
    public class MenuCardViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public MenuCardViewModel(IMvxMessenger messenger) : base(messenger)
        {
        }

        public void Init(Menu menu)
        {
            Header = menu.Header;
            InitializeMenuItems(menu);
        }

        private void InitializeMenuItems(Menu menu)
        {
            if (menu.MenuItemsList == null)
            {
                var offline = Mvx.Resolve<IOfflineContent>();
                var loadedMenu = offline.GetMenuDetailFromApi(menu.Id);
                //MenuItems = loadedMenu.MenuItemsList;
                MenuItems = new List<MenuItemHolder>();

                foreach(var item in loadedMenu.MenuItemsList)
                {
                    MenuItems.Add(new MenuItemHolder(item, this));
                }

            }
            else
            {
                //MenuItems = menu.MenuItemsList;
            }

        }

        private string _header;
        public string Header
        {
            get { return _header; }
            set
            {
                _header = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Header);
            }
        }

        private List<MenuItemHolder> _menuItems;
        public List<MenuItemHolder> MenuItems
        {
            get { return _menuItems; }
            set
            {
                _menuItems = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => MenuItems);
            }
        }
    }

    public class MenuItemHolder
    {
        MenuCardViewModel _parent;

        public int Id { get; set; }

        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
            }
        }

        private string _price;
        public string Price
        {
            get { return _price; }
            set
            {
                _price = value;
            }
        }

        public MenuItemHolder(MenuItem item, MenuCardViewModel parent)
        {
            _parent = parent;
            Id = item.Id;
            Name = item.Name;
            Price = item.Price;
        }

        private ICommand _menuItemClickCommand;
        public ICommand MenuItemClickCommand
        {
            get
            {
                _menuItemClickCommand = _menuItemClickCommand ?? new MvxCommand(DoMenuItemClickCommand);
                return _menuItemClickCommand;
            }
        }

        private void DoMenuItemClickCommand()
        {
            var item = this;
            //here I can use BaseViewModel
            _parent.Credit = 1337;
            _parent.Bonus = 68;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why you don't want to use `ItemClick` do you have a particular reason? it has the same behavior

Comment: cuz I want click just on Button and not whole Item.. I need there button with clickable function and maybe in future I will need another Click bind maybe on Text there too.

Comment: esiprogrammer is right. I don't believe you can bind to parent dataContext in mvvmcross

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MvxGridView` ItemsSource is bound to `MenuItems` which is a `List<MenuItem>` so each `MvxItemTemplate` is bound to `MenuItem`. if you want to bind `Button` to `MenuItemClickCommand` you need to move that command to `MenuItem` class.

you don't have access to parent DataContext in child. you can implement some approaches, you could use `MvvmCross Messenger plugin` for communication and request an object from parent. 
**Or** 
you could wrap parent (MenuCardViewModel) in MenuItem like:

```
public class MenuItem 
{
  MenuCardViewModel parent;
  //// pass parent to menuItem
  public MenuItem(MenuCardViewModel parent)
  {
    this.parent=parent;
  }

   public ICommand MenuItemClickCommand
   {
       get
        {
            return MvxCommand(() -> this.parent.DoMenuItemClickCommand(this));
        }
   }
}
```

and in `MenuCardViewModel`:

```
public class MenuCardViewModel
{
  ....
 public MenuCardViewModel(MenuItem menu)
 {
    /// do something
 }
}
```

Comment: ye this bind click working but there is problem I need call property from BaseViewModel which MenuCardViewModel has inherited and from MenuItem class I cant....

Comment: I updated post with my solution .. what u think about this solution?

Comment: yes. it's the same that I was trying to explain. sounds a good solution to me